# $\mathbb E[(\frac{X+1}{4}-\theta)^2]=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Let $\mathbb E[X]=\theta$

What will be $\mathbb E[(\frac{X+1}{4}-\theta)^2]=?$

I found it $$\mathbb E[(\frac{X+1}{4}-\theta)^2]=(5/8)\theta^2-(1/4)\theta+(1/16).$$

But the result is $$\mathbb E[(\frac{X+1}{4}-\theta)^2]=(1/8)\theta^2-(1/8)\theta+(1/16).$$

EDIT:

$X\sim \text{binomial}(2,\theta)$. So

$\mathbb E[X^2]=\mathbb Var[X]+(E[X])^2=2\theta(1-\theta)+4\theta^2$.

Comment: Well you definitely did not write down all details since you need some information about the second moment of $X$

Comment: @air sorry, forgot to mention the distribution of $X$. The post is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the following
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\frac{X+1}{4}-\theta\Big)^2\bigg] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\frac{X+1-4\theta}{4}\Big)^2\bigg] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{16\theta^2-8X\theta-8\theta+X^2+2X+1}{16}\bigg] =$$
$$ = \frac{1}{16}\bigg(\mathbb{E}[16\theta^2] + \mathbb{E}[-8X\theta] + \mathbb{E}[-8\theta] + \mathbb{E}[X^2] + \mathbb{E}[2X]+\mathbb{E}[1]\bigg) =$$
$$ = \frac{1}{16}\bigg(16\theta^2 -8\theta\mathbb{E}[X] -8\theta + \mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2\mathbb{E}[X]+1\bigg) =$$
$$ = \theta^2 -\frac{\theta\mathbb{E}[X]}{2} - \frac{\theta}{2} +\frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{16} + \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{8} + \frac{1}{16} = $$
$$ = \theta^2 -\frac{\theta^2}{2} - \frac{\theta}{2} +\frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{16} + \frac{\theta}{8} + \frac{1}{16} = $$
$$ = \frac{\theta^2}{2} - \frac{3\theta}{8} + \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{16} + \frac{1}{16}$$

In order to get your result, it's necessary to have $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 4\theta - 6\theta^2$.

Comment: $X~ binomial(2,\theta)$. So $\mathbb E[X^2]=\mathbb Var[X]+(E[X])^2$.

Comment: That is my derived expression is correct. Since $E[X^2]=2\theta^2+2\theta$